# Show equality of angles

Tags: geometry

Let $\ AB$ and $\ CD$ be the bases of trapezoid $\ ABCD$. Bisectors of the arms $\ AD$, $BC$ intersect the $\ BC$ and $\ AD$ segments respectively at points P and Q. Prove that $\ \angle APD$=$\ \angle BQC$. 
Please help. I don't know how to start. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $M$ and $N$ are midpoints of $BC$ and $AD$ respectively.

Then $MNQP$ is cyclic since $\angle QNP = \angle QMP = \pi/2$.

Now let $\angle PNM = x$. Then $\angle MQP =x$ and then $$\angle PQM = \pi/2-x\;\;\;\;...(1)$$ 
Since $MN$ is middle line it is parallel to $DC$ and since $\angle QNM = \pi/2+x$ so is $$\angle QDC = \pi/2+x\;\;\;\;... (2)$$

From (1) and (2) we deduce that $QPCD$ is cyclic and thus conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to prove that $\angle APD=\angle BQC$ you may have observed that tirangles $APD$ and $BQC$ are both iscoceles triangles, therefore proving that $\angle QBP=\angle PAQ$ is enough.

In order to do it you just need to prove that $QABP$ is cyclic i.e. (define $R=AD\cap BC$) $RA\cdot RQ=RB\cdot RP$. Now observe that if $M$ and $N$ are the midpoints of $AD$ and $BC$ respectively by construction $\angle PMQ=\angle QNP=90^o$ hence $QMNP$ is cyclic and $RM\cdot RQ=RN\cdot RP$.

$$\frac{RM}{RN}=\frac{RP}{RQ}$$

Notice that $MN\parallel AB\parallel DC$ by Thales' Theorem i.e. $RAB$~$RMN$: $$\frac{RA}{RB}=\frac{RM}{RN}$$ and $$\frac{RA}{RB}=\frac{RP}{RQ}$$ and finally: $$RA\cdot RQ=RB\cdot RP$$ so $ABPQ$ is cyclic as we wanted.

Comment: Why RA⋅RQ=RB⋅RP? Is there any theorem?

Comment: Power of the point $R$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point